# How to check if I have POSIX threads support

Tags: multithreading, centos, posix, slurm

I'm unable to use all cores I allocate with Slurm when running a multithreaded program (which uses POSIX threads).

I'd like to check whether my system (CentOS 7) supports POSIX threads.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: The SO you say does support POSIX threads

Comment: why do you think you are unable to use all allocated cores ?

Comment: Because I'm running a program using an option to take on 16 cores, but it only uses 1-2, although it should (theoretically) work with 16 too.